# Parenthesis checker in java

Tags: java, stack, parentheses

I have made a parenthesis checker program in java that that reads in a text stream from standard input and uses a stack to determine whether or not its parentheses are properly balanced. For example, it should print true for `[()]{}{[()()]()}` and false for `[(])`. I have made a stack class of my own for this problem:

```
public class Stack {
private char items[];
private int top;

Stack(int n){
    items = new char[n];
    top = -1; 
}

void push(char c){
    if(top == items.length-1){
        System.out.println("Stack full.");
        return;
    }
    top++;
    items[top] = c;
}

char pop(){
    if(isEmpty()){
        System.out.println("Stack empty");
        return (char)0;
    }
    char p;
    p = items[top];
    top--;
    return p;
}

boolean isEmpty(){
    if(top == -1)
        return true;
    else    
        return false;
}
```

}

The `checkValid` method below takes a String input and returns true if the parentheses matches, and false if they do not match.

```
    public static Boolean checkValid(String str){
        char sym,prev;
        Stack s = new Stack(str.length());
        for(int i=0; i<str.length();i++){
            sym = str.charAt(i);
            if(sym == '(' || sym=='{' || sym=='['){
                s.push(sym);
            }
            if(sym == ')' || sym=='}' || sym==']'){
               if(s.isEmpty()){
                   return false;
                }
               else{
                    prev = s.pop();
                    if(!isPairMatch(prev,sym))
                        return false;
               }
            }

        }
        if(!s.isEmpty())
            return false;
        return true;
    }
    public static boolean isPairMatch(char character1, char character2){
        if(character1 == '(' && character2 == ')')
            return true;
        else if(character1 == '{' && character2 == '}')
            return true;
        else if(character1 == '[' && character2 == ']')
            return true;
        else
            return false;
    }
}
```

Is there a way to print the position of the unmatched parentheses?

Comment: Well, the position of the unmatched parentheses should be the same as the size of the stack (or "size - 1").

Answer (score 1):

If your Stack, instead of holding `chars`, would hold a class that contains both the `char` and the index of that `char` in the input String, you'll be able to print the index of the unmatched parentheses.

EDIT:

This solution is only required if you want the indices of both unmatched parentheses that failed the `isPairMatch` test.

For example, if you have the String "[{}{}{})", the pair that doesn't match are the first "[" and last ")", whose indices are 0 and 7.

If you only need the index of the first unmatched parenthesis (i.e. the first "[" whose index is 0), you simply check the size of the Stack after the removal of that parenthesis. In this example, the stack would be empty when the last pair is checked, so the size of the stack would be 0, which is the index of the first char of the failed `isPairMatch` test.

Comment: Then will the program be able to check if there is correct closing parenthesis for a particular opening one?

Comment: you need a Map<k,v> where k is index, v is value i.e. parenthesis.

Comment: @rick112358 Your algorithm would stay the same. The only difference would be that instead of (for example) pushing '{' to the stack, you would push new Item('{',4). `isPairMatch` would receive two Items instead of two chars, and if the pair of chars stored in these Items don't match, you can print the indices of those chars.

Comment: I can only use stacks.. Maps are not allowed